# Storyboard Initialization

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard

I deleted the storyboard from xcode by accident , I found it in `(projectName/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard)`.

I dragged it and dropped it in the Xcode now when I run the app I have error in: `(class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate)`

What should I do to bring a functional storyboard back?

I am running xcode 6 beta 5 with Swift app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did `Product> Clean` and I re referenced the storyboard view objects and then it's worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got any specification about the error ? What you can do if you still don't find a solution is re-create the project and copy all your .swift files in it. It's not the best way I am sure but in last resort...

Answer (score 0):

In your project settings, click on your target and then under your Deployment Info, make sure the Main Interface is set to the name of your storyboard file. See screenshot below[image]